# How could I use a reference of a pointer when re-allocating memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Unlike in the C, as what i've learned about C++, there is no instruction `realloc` in C++ for it is not recommended. But when I was creating a function that concatenates strings and at the same time can be dynamically re-allocating the given strings' memory without using `vector`, I've come to need some code just like as the `realloc` instruction functioning.
So what i've come up with is that using a reference of a pointer(in the code `char* &des`) could adjust the size of memory by using the usual instruction of C++, `new` and `delete`. However, an error occured: "[Error] invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char*&' from an rvalue of type 'char*'"  Why is it impossible to initialize `char*&` type with the type `char*`? Isn't it the same as a statement `char* &des = str0`? The total code is as follows:

```
void Mystrcat(char* &des, const char* src) {
    int des_len = Mystrlen(des); // Mystrlen just returns the length of a string with the type unsigned int excluding null character
    int src_len = Mystrlen(src);
    
    char* temp_str = des;
    des = new char[des_len + src_len + 1]; 
    
    //a copy process
    for(int i = 0; i < des_len; i++) {
        des[i] = *(temp_str + i);
    }
     
    for(int i = des_len + 1; i < des_len + src_len + 1; i++)
        des[i - 1] = *(src + i - des_len - 1);

}
int main() {
    char str0[100] = "Hello";
    Mystrcat(str0, ", World!"); 
    std::cout << str0 << std::endl; //expecting "Hello, World!" to be printed
    return 0;
}
```

What i've tried before is just writing the parameter `char* des` instead of `char* &des`. But unlike in `main` function, it was not possible to get the size of total `str0` array in `Mystrcat` function by simply using `sizeof`. As a result, I thought it would be good to use pointer reference. I was expecting this a reference of a pointer parameter to be working properly because it is equal to the statement `char* &des = str0`.

Comment: You can't do this in C either: change the array by `realloc`ing its address. Neither C, nor C++, works this way.

Comment: Is it prohibited? Then for what reason is it? I thought it would be working in my guess..

Comment: Note the type of `str0` is not `char*`, so the reference can't refer to it.

Comment: I see it works.. but is there any difference between the name of `char` array and `char*`?

Comment: Right. `str0` is not a `char *`. You can only get a reference to an honest-to-goodness object that the reference claims to be a reference to. That's all it is: neither C, nor C++, works this way.

Comment: A little bit cleaner: https://godbolt.org/z/aKMhcEMoG .. Still, it's advisable to use smart pointers and wrap your stuff in an object. Or use `std::string` which is built for this.

Comment: It works because C++ creates a temporary pointer for you (in main) and initializes it to the value of `str0`. Then it calls the function, which updates the unnamed temporary... which disappears when the function returns. `str0` is never changed (it cannot be, as it is an array).

Comment: Aside from the problem of an array not producing a reference to a ptr, there is a problem in the last for loop. See [this](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: Oh, you're saying it's not valid for an array name to have a reference to a pointer.. and that's the reason why C++ recommends using `string` class. I got it, thanks for you all.

Comment: Quick side-note about C++. If you're using C++, use `std::strings` or an equivalent, instead of banging around pointers with C-strings. That way you don't have to handle the memory, it'll be done for you - probably far better than most of us could implement anyway. The people implementing the standards are **really** smart people.

Comment: I strongly guess so. I just wanted to manually create a function allocating memory by my own to improve my understanding to strings. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is:

```
char str0[100] = "Hello";
```

`str` in this case has a pinned (static) memory address. It's immutable in terms of its address -- so to speak -- because it's not a pointer to a string, but an array of characters of a size that can be evaluated at compile-time (not dynamically allocated). Making `str` itself point to a different address makes no sense and invites a whole lot of chaos. Even modifying the original pointer address to a dynamically-allocated array is chaos since you need the original address to properly free it. Think of an array of `T` as `T* const` (the address is immutable even if the contents are mutable and even if dynamically allocated, you need to keep the original address unmodified).

But in general as a non-profit advertisement of sorts, I want to encourage embracing value semantics as much as you can over pointer/reference ones. So instead of:

```
void Mystrcat(char* &des, const char* src)
{
    // Modify the address of 'des' in place.
}
```

You can do:

```
[[nodiscard]] char* Mystrcat(char* des, const char* src)
{
    // Input an address to a string and return an address to a new string.
}
```

Then you can pass an address to your array, get a pointer to a new modified copy (same thing you were doing before), and store the pointer to the new array (along with freeing it when you're done). There's little benefit to modifying things in place if you're just going to allocate a new string anyway.

This is still ignoring the conventional advice that you should use `std::string` which is what I think you need now and wholeheartedly echo over all this low-level pointer stuff and manual heap allocation and deallocation (which can be disastrous without the use of RAII when combined with thrown exceptions) But later you might want to deviate from it if the SBO is too large or too small or if the SBO optimization is counter-productive, for example but that's diving deep into things like custom memory allocators and whatnot and something you typically reserve until you encounter profiler hotspots and really know what you're doing.

Comment: Detailed,  easily undetstandable description for C++ beginner like me. Now it is clear that the name of array is not able to be dynamically allocated in compile-time, though it is an address of a first element just like normal pointers..am i right?

Comment: @ragedhumancompiler That's a lot to unpack there! My brain exploded! Definitely the identifier of `str0` you can think of as having an immutable (unchangeable) address. If I try to explain it in a simple way, it's not a pointer. It's a "pointee"! Now you can point to pointees and do arithmetic on the things that point to them, but you can't change the address of pointees.

Comment: @user21090732 Oh, my bad. To say it again, the type of `str0`, the name of the `char` array, is `char *`  but unlike normal pointer, it is not unchangeable, right? A simple thing, nice.